# See workspace in MATLAB command line terminal

Tags: matlab, command-line-interface, octave, workspace

Is there any command to see all variable names, types and **values** in command line interface? Similar to Matlab's Workspace? I already know about command `whos` but it doesn't show the values, It just shows names and types.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
vals = who;
for val = vals
    eval(val.name)
end
```